# Bootstrap row not occupying 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid layout but the row is not occupying 100% width. I am using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="center-text"  id="heading">[Enter Heaading Here]</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div height="100px" class="row border-show">
      <div class="col-4" id="one"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="two"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="three"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.center-text{
  text-align: center;
}
#heading{
  padding: 60px;
}
.border-show{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove it from the `container`. The `container` is not 100% width, and shouldn't be nested in another container.

Comment: It works by removing the parent container since it is already nested in another element container.

Answer (score 59):

In case someone else comes across this and the answer doesn't solve their problem, my issue that was causing this was because I didn't realize I was adding a row and trying to set up columns in a Bootstrap navbar. navbar already has a grid-like system in it by default, so it seems you are pushing it over the edge if you try to add columns inside of it. They aren't necessary anyway.

So if this answer doesn't solve your problem, check to see if you are inside of another Bootstrap component that already handles spacing. You may be trying to double-delimit your content!

Comment: I logged in just to upvote your answer since it was exactly the info I needed. Thanks

Comment: Bloody good tip. Spent hours trying to figure out why my rows and cols won't work, just to realize I was using Flex already.

Comment: In BS 4.6, if you need a container & row to act like normal while inside a nav, you simply need to add an override to nav's container class with:  `display: block`.

Obviously, this will have downstream effects if you're not careful, so be sure to test that this didn't wreck something else in the nav. ;)

Comment: @Robert I logged in just to upvote your comment since I thought it was nice you logged in just to upvote...

Answer (score 4):

The `container` class has this effect.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            div into <b>container</b> class
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            div into <b>container-fluid</b> class
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code will generate following image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case even container-fluid also didnot work because I used row class with the container-fluid in the same div. So, I removed the row class from the parent div and inside that I created a child div and used row class. Then it worked.

```
<div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-12">
        didn't work
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        worked
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```